# React Button Activated on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React page and when I refresh the page, the button on the page is activated and its code is run. However, when I actually press the button it doesn't register as clicked. How do I invert this behavior?

Comment: Please include your code in the question. It's hard to say otherwise.

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to receive constructive answers

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are setting the call the right way:

```
//Wrong way, the method is executed on render
<button onClick={this.save()}>Save</button> 

//Right Way, method executed on click
<button onClick={()=> this.save()}>Save</button>
//or
<button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
```